# Search functionality is not consistant in React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to implement search functionality in ReactJs using Hooks(useState).

The result I am getting is not proper since it only sets previously typed character in a search_keyword instead of each new character in a search box.

for example:

if I am writing "I" in the search box, the search_keyword will be " ".

if I am writing "In" in the search box, the search_keyword will be "I".

if I am writing "Ing" in the search box, the search_keyword will be "In".

and so on.
You can see it in the below figures.
1)
[image] Note: nothing happens with the search

2)
[image] Note: now it searches for the elements having "I" init instead of "In"

Code snipets are:

Main.js

```
const [word,setWord] = useState("");
console.log(word)
const [persons, setStudentProfiles] = useState([]);

const fetchStudentpProfiles = () => {
    fetch('https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/students')
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(data => setStudentProfiles(data.students) )
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
};
const [filterCopy,setFilterCopy] =useState([])
const handleChange = e =>{
    
    setWord(e)
  let oldList = persons.map(person => {
      
    return {
        firstName: person.firstName.toLowerCase(),
        lastName: person.lastName,
        pic:person.pic,
        email:person.email,
        city:person.city,
        company:person.company,
        grades:person.grades,
        id:person.id,
        skill:person.skill,
        tags : person.tags

    };
  });
  if(word!== ''){
    let newList = [];
    newList = oldList.filter(person =>
        person.firstName.includes(word.toLowerCase())
    );
    console.log(newList)
    setFilterCopy(newList);
  }else{
    setFilterCopy(persons);
  }
};
useEffect(() => {
    fetchStudentpProfiles()
},[]);
```

Driver Code:

```
<Filter value={word} handleChange={e =>handleChange(e.target.value)}/>
```

I have tried maintaining and manipulating separate array for search, but didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

State is updated asynchronously, so trying to use `word` after calling `setWord` will result in giving you the previous value of `word` instead of the latest value.

To fix the problem, use the `e` parameter passed to `handleChange` function which is the latest value of the input field.

```
if(e !== ''){
    let newList = [];
    newList = oldList.filter(person =>
        person.firstName.includes(e.toLowerCase())
    );
    setFilterCopy(newList);
}
else{
    setFilterCopy(persons);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Do stuff when word change
},[word]);
```

to get lastest state